# make failed when installing hplip

Tags: hp, hplip

I downloaded the latest version of hplip (3.19.5) from [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/install/index). Following the installation instructions, I ran:

```
sh hplip-3.19.5.run
```

It all worked well until the last step, where I got the following output:

```
PRE-BUILD COMMANDS
------------------
OK


BUILD AND INSTALL
-----------------
Running './configure --with-hpppddir=/usr/share/ppd/HP --libdir=/usr/lib --prefix=/usr --enable-qt4 --disable-qt5 --enable-doc-build --disable-cups-ppd-install --disable-foomatic-drv-install --disable-libusb01_build --disable-foomatic-ppd-install --disable-hpijs-install --disable-class-driver --disable-udev_sysfs_rules --disable-policykit --enable-cups-drv-install --enable-hpcups-install --enable-network-build --enable-dbus-build --enable-scan-build --enable-fax-build --enable-apparmor_build'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Command completed successfully.

Running 'make clean'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Command completed successfully.

Running 'make'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: 'make' command failed with status code 2
```

Indeed, when I run `make` I get:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: Why not simply `apt install hplip`?

Comment: @Jos because this installs version 3.16, while I need 3.19

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on? On my 19.04 hplip 3.19 is available.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04